# Is quark and gluon orbital angular momentum predicted to have the rest of the proton's spin?

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-chromodynamics, protons, lattice-model

The Phys.org news item [How did the proton get its spin?](https://phys.org/news/2017-03-proton.html) outlines various experiments that probe proton structure and are sensitive to spin, and the current news is that [CEBAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Jefferson_National_Accelerator_Facility)'s major energy upgrade will allow new kinds of investigations.

The news item identifies two experimentally measured sources of spin; the spin of the *quarks* and that of the *gluons*. Together these account for about *half* of the proton's total spin (25-30% and about 20-30%, respectively). It then says:

> There's one major source that researchers haven't yet explored: orbital angular momentum. Orbital angular momentum comes from the movement of the quarks and gluons relative to each other. While theorists have developed simulations that model this contribution, scientists haven't had the equipment to test them.

The article says there's one more place to look for a contribution, and that "theorists have developed simulations that model this contribution".

While one might now *expect* orbital angular momentum to contribute the rest of the proton's spin, *do predictions indicate* a strong enough contribution to add up to all of the proton's spin?

---

[image]

**above:** *In the 1980s, scientists discovered that a proton's three valance quarks (red, green, blue) account for only a fraction of the proton's overall spin. More recent measurements have revealed that gluons (yellow corkscrews) contribute as much as or possibly more than the quarks*. Credit: Brookhaven National Laboratory, from [here](https://phys.org/news/2017-03-proton.html).

Comment: If there are papers out on the various theory predictions, those would indicate if the theories could actually account for the 'missing' spin. Asking which theory is true might, right now, be opinion based, but pointers to the theory papers and their predictions is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit after the discussion in the comments:**

Taking a look at [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07072) CEBAF paper, they rely on the lattice QCD calculations [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00253) which predict coverage of 110% on proton's spin.

This graph in the latter demonstrates the relative components: $J^q$ stands for the total quarks' angular momentum and $J^g$ for the gluons' angular momentum (left). $J^q$ can be further decomposed (right) into the quarks' orbital angular momentum $L^q$, and the quarks' spin $\frac12\Delta\Sigma$.

[image]

**Original:**

I think that what you ask is already answered in the article :) But this is one of the open questions in particle physics, so it's natural to rise curiosity...

Q: "Is most of the remainder expected to come from orbital angular momentum of the quarks and gluons?"

Article: "There's one major source that researchers haven't yet explored: orbital angular momentum. Orbital angular momentum comes from the movement of the quarks and gluons relative to each other."

Q: "or are there still other major sources expected?"

Afaik, there is no other major proposal made to explain this. I can only add that, in general, QCD calculations still carry considerable uncertainty; so people are more prone to sit back and wait to see what happens with open QCD questions than they are for other sub-fields.

Comment: Yikes! I did miss that, thanks! But that doesn't say that *the rest* is expected to be there, it just says that's a place to look for it. The first few sentences in the block quote set the stage for *not finding* spin where it is expected. I'll make this clearer in the question. Thanks!

Comment: That's a quite good point... let's see if the answer comes up.

Comment: I added something after looking briefly at their paper.

Comment: Great - the first paragraph of section 2 of the QCD paper explains the terms shown there very nicely in fig. 2.

Comment: If you are interested in adding [the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhBz9.png) (or [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBGIm.png)) there's an image tool in the editor, and enclosing [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619) notation within single or double dollar signs yields equations and symbols.

Comment: Will be at that!

Comment: ...just noticed that I hadn't accepted, no correlation.

Comment: By the way I'm a little perplexed by the error bars on this figure...

Comment: I think the left plot starts at one o'clock. $J^q$ (green, behind, large error bar) goes counter-clockwise, and $J^g$ (red, front, small error bar) goes clockwise. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not exactly, what I meant was that the error bar for the green part looks too large if it's supposed to be 12%. I understand from the caption that the black lines are the errors, but...

Comment: I've checked the geometry of the graphic by measuring pixel locations by hand. The green segment subtends about 287°, the error bar subtends about ±43°. Dividing both by 360° gives 79.7% ± 11.9% respectively, consistent with the 79.6% ± 12% labels. It's the starting point of the green region about -17° from vertical that makes the upper error bar appear bigger than it really is, perhaps.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense when "$\pm$" is taken into account :)

Comment: It's those darn 'gotcha factors' of two, or even $1/\sqrt{\pi}$ that led one of my old teachers to set everything between 0.1 and 10 to be unity by definition at the beginning of the year.